# Enumerate partitions of identical objects

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

I have a problem concerning enumerating partitions of a set of identical objects. I know, now someone is going to talk about Stirling number of second kind, but I'm quite sure this is not the answer.

I will describe the problem with an example. Suppose to have a set of $n$ identical objects. The problem is to **enumerate** and to **generate** all the partitions obtained with $k$ subsets, like in the following example.

Let $n=5$, $k=3$. Define $B_i$, with $i=1,\dots,k$ the set of the partition. Hence, I can partition the set of $n$ objects by constructing the following partitions:

- $|B_1|=3$, $|B_2|=1$, $|B_3|=1$.
- $|B_1|=2$, $|B_2|=2$, $|B_3|=1$.

Notice that: $(i)$ must result $B_i\neq \emptyset$; $(ii)$ partitions like, for instance, $|B_1|=1$, $|B_2|=3$, $|B_3|=1$ or $|B_1|=1$, $|B_2|=1$, $|B_3|=3$ must not be considered, since are in practice already considered in the first partition (i.e. $|B_1|=3$, $|B_2|=1$, $|B_3|=1$).

Since objects are all identical, I only express the sets cardinality and I doesn't care about the specific object allocated to a set of the partition.

The problem is particular useful in the formulation of algorithms for assignment problems.

Comment: So in other words, you want to enumerate/generate [**integer partitions**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))?

Comment: @anon At a first look seems that you are right. I have to carefully read that page. Moreover, I also have to look for any algorithm inside that page for generating the partitions. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: @anon The so called "intermediate function" $p(k,n)$ should be my target, but, looking at my example, I see that the table provided $p(3,5)=1$, while I have 2 possible partitions instead. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the function $P(n,k)$ described after formula $(58)$ of [this MathWorld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html), giving the number of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts. This is always the same as the number of partitions of $n$ with largest part $k$. For this function, unlike the [intermediate function in the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Intermediate_function), $P(5,3)=2$; you’ve exhibited the two partitions of $5$ into $3$ parts, and the two partitions of $5$ with maximum part $3$ are $3+2$ and $3+1+1$. The link has a nice recurrence for $P(n,k)$, formula $(59)$:

$$P(n,k)=P(n-1,k-1)+P(n-k,k)\;,$$

with initial conditions

$$\begin{align*}
&P(n,k)=0\quad\text{if}\quad k>n\\
&P(n,n)=1\quad\text{for}\quad n\ge 0\\
&P(n,0)=0\quad\text{for}\quad n\ge 0\;.
\end{align*}$$

The recurrence is easily verified. Every partition of $n$ into $k$ parts, at least one of which is $1$, is obtained by adding a $1$ part to a partition of $n-1$ into $k-1$ parts. Every partition of $n$ into $k$ parts, all of which are at least $2$, is obtained from a partition of $n-k$ into $k$ parts by adding $1$ to each part.

Comment: Do you have idea of any algorithm for generating the partitions?

Comment: @Jean: I’m afraid not. If I were doing it myself, I think that I’d start with the partition that has $k-1$ ones and try to find a nice way systematically to transfer single units from the largest part to the smaller ones in all possible ways.

Comment: @Brian: Don Knuth gives an algorithm that does pretty much what you write, except there's a step that can make more than single transfers (see my answer).

Comment: @joriki: Thanks. (It's nice to know that my programming instincts aren't  completely dead!)

Answer (score 4):

Don Knuth gives an algorithm for generating all partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts in Algorithm H on p. $2$ of pre-fascicle 3B of *The Art of Computer Programming*, which is a draft of Sections 7.2.1.4–5. This is available as a gzipped PostScript file [on Knuth's website](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/fasc3b.ps.gz) and as a low-quality PDF [elsewhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22notice%20that%20the%20operation%20of%20going%20from%20one%22).

Here's the algorithm (in my words; Knuth gives it in pseudocode):

Denote the parts by $a_1$ to $a_k$. Start out with $n-k+1,1,\dotsc,1$. Generate partitions by moving $1$ from $a_1$ to $a_2$ as long as this doesn't make $a_2$ greater than $a_1$. Then look for the first $j$ with $a_j\lt a_1-1$. If there isn't one, you're done. If there is, increment $a_j$ by $1$, set all parts between $a_1$ and $a_j$ to $a_j$ and choose $a_1$ to make the sum come out right; then go back to generating partitions.

Comment: This answer completes the one that I accepted! From a practical point of view, I can say that it is very helpful. Then, +1!